# using array to tally votes

Tags: c, arrays, sum

So I'm working on this program where I need to use arrays, to record the sums of votes for a user inputed number of id's where they will vote for an option a,b,c or d. at the end I will print the sum with the highest votes and declare them the winner. This being said, it's understood that no one may vote more than once. This is where my problem is occurring, I'm trying to set the array for id's(voter_id) to have every value in the area be false until the user specifies his id and then votes, where the value should then be 0, at the id spot in the array.

additionally My program is not printing the printf for successfully voting for a candidate. printf("Successfully voted for %c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int id;
int a_size;
char ch;
int sum[4];
int i;
int max;
int voter_id[a_size];

sum[0]=0;
sum[1]=0;
sum[2]=0;
sum[3]=0;
voter_id[a_size]=1;

//scan for the array size
            scanf("%d", &a_size);

//need to loop and scan for characters while incrementing up the array size until we reach the final array slot
    while(id>0 && id!=-1){
        printf("What is your id?\n");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        for (i=0;i<a_size;i++){
            voter_id[a_size]=1;
            printf("You have already voted. You cannot vote again.");
            continue;

    }
        printf("Welcome %d, which vote would you like to place?\n", id);
            scanf("%c\n", &ch);

                if (ch== 'A' || ch=='a'){
                    printf("You have successfully voted for A\n");
                        sum[0]++;
                }
                if (ch== 'B' || ch=='b'){
                    printf("You have successfully voted for B\n");
                        sum[1]++;
                }
                if (ch== 'C' || ch=='c'){
                    printf("You have successfully voted for C\n");
                        sum[2]++;
                }
                if (ch== 'D' || ch== 'd'){
                    printf("You have successfully voted for D\n");
                        sum[3]++;
                }
    }
    max=1;

        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            if (sum[i]>max){
                max=sum[i];
            }
            'A'== sum[0];
            'B'== sum[1];
            'C'== sum[2];
            'D'== sum[3];
            printf("%c wins with %d votes", &sum[i], &max);
        }
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think this means `'A'== sum[0];`?

Comment: On the part why the messages are not printed: That's `scanf`'
s doing. `scanf("%d", ...)` reads an integer (and may not succeed, which you should check) and keeps the input pointer where it is after the number, i.e. before the new-line. The next char you read is a new-lin character and not any of the letters. You could skip white-space first with `scanf(" %c", &c)`; note the space before `%c`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, take the following as advice and spend the required time doing it, it will reward you later

- **Format your code so it looks beautiful**

believe it or not, this can make you a better programmer.

1. This in a loop causes problems

   ```
   scanf("%c\n", &ch);
   ```

   because you input the `'\n'` when you press enter, and then the `scanf()` will consume it on the iteration right after the one where you input your data, you need to explicitly ignore white space characters for the `"%c"` specifier, like this

   ```
   scanf(" %c\n", &ch);
   ```
2. This comparison `'D'== sum[3];` does absolutely nothing, I suppose that you tried to assign to the character constant and found this as a workaround, which means that you don't understand what the `==` operator is for, it's for comparison.
3. This is also wrong

   ```
   printf("%c wins with %d votes", &sum[i], &max);
   ```

   because you are passing the address of the `i`th element in the `sum` array, and then you pass the address of `max` which is also wrong.

   This means that you don't know why you use the `&` address of operator in `scanf()`, there you need to pass the address of the variable to modify it inside `scanf()` but in the case of `printf()` what you need to pass is the value.

   If you want to check who won, then

   ```
   int index;

   max   = sum[0];
   index = 0;
   for (i = 1 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
    {
       if (max < sum[i])
        {
           index = i;
           max   = sum[i];
        }
     }
    printf("%c wins with %d votes", index + 'A', max);
   ```

   in this particular case this will work because `'B' == 'A' + 1` and `'C' == 'A' + 2` and so on.